# User Control value not updating, unable to retrieve

Tags: vb.net, webforms, user-controls

Totally stumped on this one, everything looks like it should work fine. When I try to get the value of the textbox, it always ends up being what was initially loaded, not any updated value. Please help.

**UPDATE**
Created a stand alone project to recreate issue. Loaded data with standard Page_Load and worked the way it should. The project, however uses

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As EventArgs)
```

When I changed to loading the data that way, it failed. Not really sure what my options are, please assist if able.

WorkOrder.aspx:

(there IS a DevEx grid on the page too, but I can find no relevance there. Both controls are in the root of an asp:Content tag)

```
<uc:WebUserControl ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" />
 <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateRecord" runat="server">Update</asp:LinkButton>
```

WorkOrder.aspx.vb:

```
    Protected Sub UpdateRecord_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UpdateRecord.Click
     Dim x As String = WebUserControl1.EmailValue
    End Sub
```

UserControl1.ascx:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="eMail" runat="server" CssClass="ContractTextEntry"
     Text="" MaxLength="125" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
```

UserControl1.ascx.vb:

```
    Public Property EmailValue As String
    Get
        Return eMail.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        eMail.Text = value
    End Set
    End Property
```

Value of text box gets set with simple ADO and a proc:

```
eMail.Text = myReader.Item("Email")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to loading the data with

```
 Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
```

That didnt work for loading the data, but a colleague suggested adding HANDLES

```
Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
```

and all became right in the world!